# How to load a fixed width file in hadoop cascading

Tags: hadoop, cascading

How to load a fixed width file in hadoop cascading or should we use any external UDF to load the files based on the particularity of the fields?
How should we invoke an external UDF in hadoop cascading?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a fixed width tap that I know of. Custom taps are pain to implement (trust me I know). So let's not worry about that.

The easiest thing to do to use the [TextLineScheme](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.1/javadoc/cascading/scheme/hadoop/TextLine.html) with your Tap. The first thing the input pipe should do is go to a custom [Function](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.0/javadoc/cascading/operation/Function.html). You're input scheme is a Tuple with two columns: offset and line. You want to work with the line (ignore the offset). The function to parse the columns and return a new TupleEntry with the [Fields](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.1/javadoc/index.html?cascading/scheme/hadoop/TextLine.html) defined by your actual data. When you extend [BaseOperation](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.1/javadoc/index.html?cascading/scheme/hadoop/TextLine.html), pass the Fields you're function will return in the `super(new Fields("FirstName", "LastName", "etc))`;

Once you've done this, pass the output pipe of the function to the rest of your downstream Flow.